# Equivalent statements about accumulation point of a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence and $c  \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

I want to show that the following statements in quotes are equivalent.

I've attempted $(i) \Rightarrow (ii)$ and stuck on $(ii) \Rightarrow (iii)$. I've seen the proof $(iii) \Rightarrow (i)$.

> (i) $c $ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
>
> (ii) Every open ball $B(c, ε)$ with $ε ∈ \mathbb{R}_{>0}$
>   contains infinitely many $a_n$.
>
> (iii) Either $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: a_{n_k}=c$ or every open ball $B(c, \epsilon)$ with $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ contains at least one $a_n \ne c.$

$(i) \implies (ii):$ If $c $ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ then there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $a_{n_k} \to c$ -- that's for all $\epsilon > 0$ there's $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \ge K$, we have $|a_{n_k} -c| < \epsilon $, that's $a_{n_k} \in (c+\epsilon, c-\epsilon), $ i.e. $a_{n_k} \in B(c, \epsilon)$ *It contains infinitely many $a_{n_k}$ hence it contains infinitely many $a_n$ by definition*.

Does this make sense? I don't know how to write that last sentence (in italics).

$(ii) \implies (iii):$ How do you do this? I was told this is trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that (ii) holds, i.e. every open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ contains infinitely many $a_n$. If $(a_n)$ contains a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ always equal to $c$, then we are done. Thus, we might as well assume that $(a_n)$ does not have a subsequence that is always equal to $c$.

Fix now a ball $B(c,\epsilon)$. By the assumption in (ii), this ball contains infinitely many $a_n$. Hence, $B(c,\epsilon)$ contains a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ of $(a_n)$. Because we cannot have $a_{n_k}= c$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there is some $a_{n_k} \neq c$. In particular, $B(c,\epsilon)$ contains some $a_n \neq c$.